# Can anybody explain the meaning of the DSolve's result?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

The `DSolve` in the following code gives a solution to a nonlinear PDE, which is like a certain implicit solution according to the documentation (see the second example in *Nonlinear differential equation* for `DSolve` in V.9).

```
DSolve[{D[f[x, t], t] + 2*f[x, t]^2*D[f[x, t], x] == 0}, f[x, t], {x, t}]
```

> Solve[C[1][f[x, t], t - x/(2 f[x, t]^2)] == 0, f[x, t]]

I cannot understand the result. Could you explain the solution, say, what it really is? How can we see it more clearly? Or can we solve this equation *analytically* (with some appropriate/necessary condition)? Thank you very much.

Comment: It is an implicit form of the solution. `C[1]` stands for an arbitrary function (well, say, a continuously differentiable one).  Picking such a function, one can solve the equation for a particular solution `f[x, t]`.

Comment: [These notes](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahhwi/LTCC/sectionA-firstorder.pdf) have an explanation (section A.5).  The variable `C[1]` corresponds to the function $F$.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks, Sir. May i know the title of the book or notes or its source?

Comment: They are lecture notes.  I assume they are by the author of the webpages -- just look for the homepage from the link.

Comment: @MichaelE2 i found there is a mistake in the example of A.3

Comment: A.3 seems irrelevant to the problem posted above, no?  Perhaps tell the author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify an arbitrary function `C[1][]`, for example

```
 s = 
 DSolve[{D[f[x, t], t] + 2*f[x, t]^2*D[f[x, t], x] == 0}, 
  f[x, t], {x, t}]

(* Solve[f[x, t] == C[1][x - 2 t f[x, t]^2], f[x, t]]*)

s /. C[1][e_] :> e

(*Out[]= {{f[x, t] -> (-1 - Sqrt[1 + 8 t x])/(
   4 t)}, {f[x, t] -> (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 8 t x])/(4 t)}}*)
```

Comment: When I run the code in V.9, it gives me the same answer as in my original question. Now I understood that `C[1][f(x,t), g(x,t)]` represented an implicit function. Thank you.

Comment: Sir, did you mean `Solve[f[x, t] == x - 2 t f[x, t]^2, f[x, t]]`? Your code does not reproduce your answer...

Comment: @user55777 The code works in version 11.3